# How to hide the keyboard in objective-c

Tags: cocoa-touch

I have a simple view with a textbox and a UIButton.  When I click the UIButton I simply want to hide the keyboard that is currently in the view.  Is this a simple delegate I can add to the controller or something more complex?

Of the answers that exist on SO already I haven't found one that has a full solution for this context.  Any help would be great!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide keyboard when user touches uiview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/963571/hide-keyboard-when-user-touches-uiview)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try something like:
`[TextField resignFirstResponder];`
Where TextField is the name of your text field.

Comment: The actual method that works is [zipField resignFirstResponder];

Answer (score 4):

This is how you hide the UITextField when you hit the return button:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

   // do whatever you have to do

   [textField resignFirstResponder];
   return YES;
}
```

This is how you hide when you hit an UIButton:

```
- (void)hideTextField:(UITextField *)textField {

   // do whatever you have to do

   [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```