# iPhone: dismiss keyboard when user touches background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, first-responder

I have read some other articles like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306240/iphone-dismiss-keyboard-when-touching-outside-of-textfield) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963571/hide-keyboard-when-user-touches-uiview) but unfortunately there are some differences in my code that won't make these work (so please don't suggest these answers).

I would like to dismiss the keyboard when the user taps the background. Normally this would be easy, except that my `UITextField` objects are inside a `UIScrollView` which makes it so I can't catch the touch events (the `UIScrollView` swallows them so they don't reach the base view). One way to get around this is to register for a generic gesture (a tap), but this catches all taps, including the ones intended for the submit button.

So basically, 'touchesBegan:withEvent:' wont work because it never gets called, and gestures wont work because they dont account for button presses.

Here's the question: is there some way to detect a simple tap on a `UIScrollView`? Once I detect the tap I know how to do the rest. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `touchesBegan:withEvent` on the superview of the scrollview, but what about subclassing UIScrollView and handling the touch there? You can then proceed normally with a call to super's implementation to keep from stepping on the UIScrollView's toes:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    /* Insert code to dismiss keyboard if needed */

    // This makes sure scrolling proceeds normally.
    [super touchesBegain:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: So, if the user only tapped the screen will `touches` have a size of 1? Also, will this interfere with buttons in the ScrollView?

Comment: The general theory is that the event will be called each time a finger touches the screen. Since it is theoretically possible that two fingers touch the screen at _exactly_ the same time, the touches are passed as a set. Practically speaking, touches almost always has one touch, and the messages are sent with very close temporal proximity for touches with many fingers. As for the buttons, they will have a higher priority in the responder chain, and I believe they will consume their own touches without the scroll view knowing anything.

Comment: You've been great, thanks. So do you have any ideas on how to differentiate between a touch and a scroll?

Comment: @mtmurdock: For the purpose of not dismissing the keyboard when the user is actually trying to scroll?

Comment: Yea basically. I actually implemented it simply checking if `[touches count] == 1` and that seems to work just fine. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into same problem. While in IOS 6.0, it was working fine, but as soon i switched to IOS 5.0, it started to show the same behaviour you have mentioned.

Workout for IOS 5.0 - You should use the UITapGestureRecognizer. Then set its delegate to self and implement the following delegate method

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch;
```

as

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    return ! ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIControl class]]);
}
@end
```

above code will verify that the object under touch is not a UIButton or any control element, then only handle the touch

I hope it would solve your problem.

Comment: [link] (http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Writing_iOS_4_Code_to_Hide_the_iPhone_Keyboard) here is another strategy to handle the same